# Usage of "->" in Scheme/SICP

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, sicp

While talking about Painters, SICP uses a procedure defined as follows:

```
(define (segments->painter segment-list)
   ...
)
```

Unfortunately, the text doesn't (yet?) say anything about what the `->` represents. What is the usage of `->` in Scheme? Is it an OOP-ish thing to show, for example, that segments is to be treated as a 'method' on a painter (or perhaps vice-versa)? The only place I've seen the `->` notation is in C, and of course we're not dealing with pointers here, so I'm a bit unclear on how its used or what convention it's used in.

Comment: It’s simply a part of the name of the function. The characters -> are allowed in identifiers. The naming convention is to use -> in names, when the function converts one type of value into another - but is just a convention.

Comment: If you got stuck with this syntax, SICP is not yet for you,  you need 10 years to finish it.  Start with Friedman's courses, etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is just a part of the allowed characters of a name so it is simply a part of the variable `segments->painter` that happens to evaluate to a procedure.

While not having any real syntactical meaning there are common naming conventions in Scheme that is designed to give information to the reader of the source. A procedure like `a->b` transforms an argument of type/category a to one of type/category b. Eg. `number->string` takes a number and a radix and evaluates them to a string representation of that number. Your example takes `segments` and evaluates to a `painter` and I don't need to know what a segment of painter is or how the method works to assume it. In Java one would call the same `segmentsToPainter` and every java developer would understand what it does.

Another example of the same is procedures ending with question mark. Eg. `done?` and `color?` are examples of procedures that checks the arguments for something and returns a true or a false value. Java does the same with `is` and `has` prefix, eg. `isDone` or `hasColor`, without the `is` or `has` having any real syntactical meaning other than naming convention.